# mget No Such file or directory

Tags: linux, command-line, ftp

I'm connected to one of our file servers and am trying to pull down (via `ftp` and `mget`) a folder to a local directory. 50% of the `mget` command works successfully until it gets to a JAR file that is absolutely there on the server.  It gives me  the following error:

```
local: dist/MyProgram.jar remote: dist/MyProgram.jar
local: dist/MyProgram.jar: No such file or directory
```

The command I am using is a simpl mget

```
ftp> prompt
ftp> mget *
```

I am absolutely in the right directory and absolutely have a solid connection.  Setting the `prompt` flag to prevent me from being prompted on each get. Any ideas?

Comment: what do you make of the relative path (i.e. `dist/`) in `local: dist/MyProgram.jar` ? I don't believe `mget` can handle such a file-spec (at least on the ftp versions I'm used to) and I don't think `mget` will recurse into subdirs when given the argument '*'. What happens if you just ask for `dir *`, do you see your jar file there? Might help to add version info on Linux version and your ftp client and a tag for your linux distro. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `mget` doesn't behave recursively. I thought it would recurse down my directory tree and copy everything over as-is. You need to run it at every level of your project. It was treating `dist/MyProgram.jar` as a filename.

Answer (score 7):

```
wget -r ftp://name:passwd@ftp.com/somedir/
```

Comment: While not an answer to the question... seriously, just use wget.